# eclipse c++ debug: no source available for gl_draw

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, glut, fltk

The code is designed to load a .obj file, draw, rotate camera around mesh (this is ongoing) and display rotation value when the mouse button is clicked. I am using eclipse C++ IDE with FLTK. When the mouse button is clicked the window crashes. The error message when debugging is "no source available for gl_draw".

The code is as follows:

```
    void onMouseButton(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    switch(button){
    case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN){
            // Print value on object
            char s[40];
            sprintf(s, "ROT=%.2f", g_rotation);
            glRasterPos2f(60,40);
            gl_draw(s, strlen(s));

        }
    }
}
```

The main code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    Fl_Window win(WIDTH,HEIGHT, "Wavefront");
    win.resizable(win);
    win.show(argc, argv);
    // Docs say to add glut subwindow /after/ calling win.show()
    win.begin();
    // initialize and run program
    //glutInit(&argc, argv);                                      // GLUT initialization
            glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH-20, HEIGHT-20);
            glutInitWindowPosition(10,10); // place inside parent window
            glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
            glutCreateWindow("Ear");
            glutDisplayFunc(display);                                   // register Display Function
            glutIdleFunc( display );                                    // register Idle Function
            glutMouseFunc( onMouseButton );
            glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );                               // register Keyboard Handler
            initialize();
            obj.Load("Ear_obj.obj");
             //gl_draw(s, strlen(s));
            glutMainLoop();
    win.end();// run GLUT mainloop
    return 0;
}
```

If  gl_draw(s, strlen(s)); is removed code run as expected , therefore loads the mesh, draws it, displays the mesh as the camera is rotated but would do nothing if the mouse is clicked. 
Is the a way to display any text when the mouse is clicked or is there a step I am missing that is causing the error?

Comment: Has gl_font been set anywhere?

Comment: @cup I'll bet you're right: that's the reason of the crash. The program have a number of other problems, though.